# How to get clicked element from the DOM using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In jQuery, I can get the element that was clicked in the DOM using the following

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    var element = $(event.target);
    console.log(element);
    ....
}
```

How would I do the same with Angular? I've searched for it online but all of the solutions were related to elements that had an `ng-click` attribute like links and buttons. I'd like to listen to the click event for the entire DOM and then get the element that was clicked(p, li, a, span etc.) Is there anyway I can achieve this using Angular only or would I have to use jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the ng-click on the body

```
 <body ng-click="go($event)">
```

In your controller:

```
 $scope.go = function($event){
     alert($event.currentTarget );
 };
```

Comment: Would you also need to use `$event.stopPropagation()`?

Comment: Potentially on any inner ng-clicks if the detweiller doesn't want the body ng-click triggered

Comment: Thanks. If you don't mind me asking, what is this `$event.stopPropagation()` you speak of? Do I need to use it too?

Comment: If you had ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()" on say a button and you clicked the button it would not trigger the body ng-click as well

Answer (score 2):

From the docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick and https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-:

`Event object is available as $event`

html

```
<div ng-click="functionName()"></div>
```

js

```
$scope.functionName = function($event){}
```

Comment: Thanks. Apparently, I need to pass the `$event` as a parameter in `functionName()` too.